# Development Mode - copies of template spreadsheets made by other users

Tags: google-apps-script

Are copies of spreadsheets that include a library in development mode suppose to update immediately when changes to the master script (owned by another account) are made?

I have created a script >> saved a version >> added a library reference (in development mode)  to it inside a spreadsheet  >> made several copies of that ss (under the same account used to create it) and they all update automatically when the master script is changed.  That works.

However, when I create a copy of the template spreadsheet under a different account, the changes do not update at all even though I can still see the library reference and it's still in development mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the access the account has to the actual library. If they have editor access then development mode is respected, otherwise if they are only a reader of the script library then it uses the selected version. Here's a link to the relevant section in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries#testAndDebug).