# How do I make sure that multiple Google Sheets files in a folder are protected in one go?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a working code that allows me to protect multiple Google Sheets files located inside a folder and to add editors.

But, I have to run the code multiple times in accordance to the number of files in the folder. For example: If I have seven files in the folder, I have to run it seven times.

How do I make sure the files are protected with one run?

This is my humble attempt of putting together the code:

```
function AddEditorsProtection(){
var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Folder Name').next(); //Add Folder name
var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"); 
while (spreadSheets.hasNext()) // Loops through all Spread Sheets inside the folder.

var sheet = spreadSheets.next();
var name = sheet.getName();

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());
var firstSheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
var secondSheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[1];
var thirdSheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[2];

spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(firstSheet);
var protection = firstSheet.protect().setDescription('Description 1');
protection.addEditors(['Editor 1 Email', 'Editor 2 Email']); // Insert list of editors.

spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(secondSheet);
var protection = secondSheet.protect().setDescription('Description 2');
protection.addEditors(['Editor 1 Email', 'Editor 2 Email']); // Insert list of editors.

spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(thirdSheet);
var protection = thirdSheet.protect().setDescription('Description 3');
protection.removeEditors(['Editor 1 Email', 'Editor 2 Email']); // Insert list of editors.
};
```

I followed this helpful post to get to where I am:
[Using scripts across multiple files without creating a new script in every file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57297071/using-scripts-across-multiple-files-without-creating-a-new-script-in-every-file)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `How do I make sure the files are protected with one run?` and your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal? By the way, in your script, `while (spreadSheets.hasNext())` is used for only the line of `var sheet = spreadSheets.next();`. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Aloha! @Tanaike - My apologies for not making it clearer. My end goal is to add protection and editors to a group of files inside a master folder **with just running one script.** I have 296 files (same number of tabs and name) distributed among 5 sub folders. And hopefully I could use the same code or similar structure to format specific ranges to add background color and font. Thank you for pointing out that line of code, I am new to scripting so I am figuring out things as I try to solve problems.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Comment: Aloha - yes, @ARANYA MUKHERJEE replied, I was waiting to get others feedback. The code I provided works, but unfortunately, is not assigning the protection at once. I have to click on the "run" bottom according to the number of files in the folder. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in feature to protect or edit the protection of several sheets at once but Google Apps Script could be used to automated this task or an add-on created by yourself or by someone else.

Reference

[Use Add-ons & Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

[Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

However, if you're only worried about accidental edits, you can use:

```
protection.setWarningOnly(true);
```

This applies to all users, including the owner. Unfortunately, there is no way to set the warning text to something more helpful and the user can choose to ignore it.

Here's a script that may achieve what you want:

```
function protectAllSheets(){
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    let protection = sheet.protect();
    protection.setWarningOnly(true);
}
```